# Finding the parent object in a self-referencing Java class

Tags: java, class, parent, self-reference

I've created a class to mimic a file structure for a program (a text-based game) I'm working on. This is a simplified version:

```
public class Dir {
  public Dir(String name, Dir[] subdirs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.subdirs = subdirs;
  }
  public String name;         //directory name
  public Dir[] subdirs;       //Sub-directories
}
```

The structure would be created using something like this (only much, much bigger):

```
private Dir root = new Dir("root",new Dir[]{
  new Dir("first",new Dir[]{
    new Dir("child1",null),
    new Dir("child2",null),
    new Dir("child3",new Dir[]{
      new Dir("child3-1",null)
    })
  }),
  new Dir("second",null),
});
```

And finally, the current directory is tracked in the variable currentDir, and will change arbitrarily based on user input:

```
Dir currentDir = root.subdir[0].subdir[3].subdir[0];
```

I want to be able to find the parent object of a given object. In this case, currentDir has a parent named "child3", which has a parent named "first", which has a parent named "root", which doesn't have a parent. How best to go about that? Also, any tips on a better way to do this are appreciated - I've plenty of programming experience, just not a lot in Java.

***Edit:***

I ended up creating a recursive subroutine, to be run once the directories have been set up:

```
private void setParent(Dir thisDir) {
  //Loop through every subdir
  for(Dir tmp : thisDir.subdirs) {
    //set this as the parent on each sub-dir
    tmp.parent = thisDir;
    //then call setParent on each sub-dir
    setParent(tmp);
  }
}
```

I still have to track any changes to the parent if a directory is moved, but this works, for now at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a `parentDir` reference in each `Dir` object.

In the constructor of `Dir` you'd do something like

```
for (Dir subdir : subdirs)
    subdir.parent = this;
```

I realize that it introduces some redundancy and annoying invariants in your code. I guess the alternative is to have a simple function that recursively finds the parent of a dir-object by searching from the root. Could be done by something like this:

```
Dir findParent(Dir root, Dir d) {

    if (Arrays.asList(subdirs).contains(d))
        return this;

    for (Dir subdir : subdirs) {
        Dir parent = findParent(subdir, d);
        if (parent != null)
            return parent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

A side-note: I strongly suggest you use empty arrays instead of `null` for directories that don't have any children. That avoids a lot of conditional code (if-statements).

Comment: The downside with that approach is that as the number of subdirs grow, so does the number of steps. I may implement a top-down (where "root" is the top level), recursive subdir finder, to be run once it's populated... I was hoping that there would be some sort of built-in parent reference, but alas, that seems not to be the case. Thanks for the empty array suggestion though, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Add a parent reference to your Dir class and climb-up the tree:

```
public class Dir {
  public Dir(String name, Dir parent, Dir[] subdirs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.subdirs = subdirs;
    this.parent = parent;
  }
  public String name;         //directory name
  public Dir[] subdirs;       //Sub-directories
  public Dir parent;
}
```

But your one liner instantiation won't work ...

Comment: This causes a chicken-and-egg problem, since you require the user to provide both children and parent for constructing a Dir object.

Answer (score 0):

Either store the parentDir for each Dir, just as aioobe suggested, search for the parent every time you want it (very bad idea), or use an existing library, like classpath-explorer. That might just do what you need.

JDK 7 also has some more advanced file handling stuff, so if your Dir() structure reflects the actual file system, you might not even need to implement it yourself.